# Htaccess redirecting error pages

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite server errors (404, 500, etc) to url like this:

```
example.com/error.php?n=404
example.com/error.php?n=500
```

how to make it?

**UPD:**

Is there a universal way to handle all errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?n=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?n=500
```